# Extract ad-hoc boundaries from pdf

Tags: qgis, pdf, boundaries

I have a scanned map of the US in pdf that, in addition to state boundaries, has "delivery territories." These territories are exclusive areas within the US where different companies deliver their products. The boundaries of these territories may cross state lines (covering at least part of two or more states), or they may be contained within a state. These boundaries are defined at the zip code level.

I have already georeferenced the pdf map and if I overlap a shapefile of zip codes, the boundaries of the territories match the boundaries of the zip codes (though territories cover many zip codes, and often a complete state or more). What I want to do is to recover the information about delivery territories from this map. Is there a way to do this? In the map, state boundaries are represented using red lines, while delivery territories are represented using black lines. I can't post  the map online because of copyright issues, but I got the following map online that represents a similar setting. In this setting, I would like to recover the territories, for example, at the zip code level, that correspond to each color (in my case, a different color would represent a different company)

Edit: My map is a white map with only the boundaries in color (red and black). The map below would be very similar to mine if instead of colors representing different areas, it only had the boundaries.

[image]

Comment: It should be doable by overlaying the zip polygons on the raster zone map, and taking the majority colour of the zone pixels in each zip polygon. *But* the black outlines might mess this up, especially in the crinkly bits on the East coast. Maybe set anything black to "missing" and ignore? Hmm...

Comment: I should have made this clear: the map is white, with only boundaries in color (red and black). It is not exactly as the one I posted. It would be very similar if instead of having colors, the posted map had only boundaries. I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Oh that sounds even trickier...

Comment: This is what I did in the end. Instead of trying to export the lines that define boundaries, I used the lines of the georeferenced pdf to create a new shapefile layer (Polygon) to add Features, where these are the respective delivery areas. I did it "by hand" and then I used "Join attributes by location" to join these areas with, for example, a layer of zip codes. As this doesn't directly address my question (how to export boundaries from the pdf), I'll leave this as a comment.